# Скрипт для перезапуска неактивных процессов python

Tags: python

Есть скрипт, который может выполняться очень долгое время и если он станет неактивным (упадет, зависнет) нужно его перезапустить.

Какие программы, библиотеки, скрипты, модули смогут перезапускать неактивные процессы питона?

Запускать буду на windows и linux (Raspbian)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Программы подобного вида называются watchdog (сторожевая собака). Но вот только отследить, что процесс упал - просто, то отследить, что процесс завис - сложно, а иногда никак нельзя. Скрипт может молотить локальный массив и просто грузить процессор, а может зависнуть в бесконечном цикле.

Как я делал подобное. Скрипт должен как то обновлять данные, что он работает. Например, писать в лог или обновлять дату файла. Вачдог запускается cron или чем то другим раз в минуту (пять минут, час) и проверяет этот файл. Если ничего не поменялось - нужно перезапускать.

В другом проекте я просто встроил в скрипт маленький http сервер, который просто отдавал статистику. вачдог скрипт делал curlом запрос и смотрел на результат. Также вачдог умел отправлять письма-отчеты и слал смс, если перезапуск не удавался.

Как по мне, то вачдог - это специфическая программа, которая пишется под каждую конкретную ситуацию. Но в современных системах они часто уже достаточно хорошо встроены. В линуксе тот же systemd умеет перезапускать сервисы, если они упали (но есть ли он на малинке - не знаю).

Также в линуксах можно использовать [runit](https://evasive.ru/1a2937134c874bbb516d0a6811aecb07.html).

В виндовсе если сделать сервис, то сама винда сможет перезапускать упавший сервис.

Некоторые админы пишут скрипты вачдога в таком виде:

```
вечный цикл:
  проверить, запущен ли скрипт
  если не запущен и счетчик перезапусков не превысил лимит, перезапустить
  спать 5 минут
```

Но у этого подхода есть один недостаток - этот скрипт также может упусть. Но его сильный плюс - его легко сделать кроссплатформенным.

Comment: Я искал 'python watchdog' и мне выдавал модуль [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) в pypi, который следит за файловой системой, что не то, что нужно :)

Comment: я знаю. Но его можно также использовать. Пусть Ваш скрипт время от времени обновляет условный файл. А скрипт вачдога будет за этим файлом следить. Если за какое-то опять же условжное время файл не изменился - тревога.

Comment: А каким образом кроссплатформенно реализовать `проверить, запущен ли скрипт`? Сам делал и с `while True:` и с оберткой в кроне, но имхо, оба решения платформозависимы.

Comment: возможно чтение [этого](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) поможет.